# ESTA payment not processing

Tags: esta, payment

I am trying to apply for my ESTA, but every time I submit the payment, I get an error saying "The charge is suspected to be fraudulent. Call your bank to determine the problem. Alternatively, use a different debit or credit card."

I have contacted my bank, and they have advised that they cannot see any charge was even attempted, and they are not blocking any charges, so the problem must be the ESTA system. I have tried paying with a total of 4 different cards now, and none are working, I keep getting the same error.  This is obviously an issue with the ESTA website.

Has anyone else had this problem?? How do I proceed?  I cannot even call ESTA as I don't have an 'order number' yet.  Does anyone have a contact phone number for them? I need to apply for this visa today in order to have it approved for my upcoming visit this week!

Comment: Can you try using a different web browser?

Comment: Or from a different location.  Maybe your IP address is the problem.

Comment: Are you completely sure you are using the genuine ESTA site?

Comment: Do your credit card have any restriction to buy abroad? So, I will pay some like this using my Brazilian Credit card, I need to "say" to bank that I will pay some abroad. In my case, I can do it using the bank app...

Comment: Are you using a VPN?

Comment: Did you specifically call your bank's fraud department? I've had issues where the bank's regular staff have assured me that everything is fine but the fraud department could see that there was indeed something wrong and were able to fix it.

Comment: DJClayworth's question above is a very good one. If you Googled "ESTA application" instead of going direct to the esta.cbp.dhs.gov site, you may have ended up visiting one of many sites that sometimes sound official (e.g. www.official-esta.com) but aren't. Even if they're a 'trustworthy' business, they'll add on a surcharge (you should only be paying the official $14 charge) to submit an application on your behalf. If they're not a trustworthy business, you'll be giving them a lot of personal data and could get ripped off.

Comment: A colleague accidentally used one of these unofficial sites.  He got the ESTA but it cost him over $80 rather than $14.  He complained and managed to get a refund so that his net cost was only $14.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify.  Putting on hold.